# В setInterval if блок продолжает выполняться

Tags: javascript

Есть следующий код

```
head_3 = 300;

function jump () {
    setInterval(() => {
        if (head_3 > 250) {
            arc_end--;
        } else {
            arc_end++;
        }
    }, 20);
}
```

Когда head_3 достигает значения 250, то if блок почему-то все равно продолжает выполняться и вместе с ним выполняется и else блок

Comment: Откуда взялся arc_end? Добавьте воспроизводимый пример.

Answer (score 0):

Интервал сам по себе не останавливается. Его надо останавливать самому через функцию **[clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval)**. Получается примерно так:

```
function jump () {
    let intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        if (head_3 > 250) {
            arc_end--;
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        } else {
            arc_end++;
        }
    }, 20);
}
```